# Web API Project Template is missing from the "Add new project" dialog

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've encountered an issue regarding the Empty "ASP.NET Web API Project Template" extension (downloaded from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a989a149-4bc3-4292-ac8a-5101ee1722d7

After I installed it, (with all instances of VS closed) I couldn't see it anywhere in the new project console:

[image]

As you can see, it's not present (although I know for sure it supposed to be there since I have it at work.
Furthermore, I can see it in the "Extensions and Update" menu:
[image]

And it is enabled.
I just don't understand what I did wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thnx

Comment: Rotem, try installing [ASP.NET and Web Tools](http://ASP.NET%20and%20Web%20Tools%20for%20Visual%20Studio%202013) for Visual Studio 2013 (assuming your VS version is 2013). Don't forget to restart Visual Studio afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Web Api after u choose MVC 4 Web Application
1- Choose Asp.net MVC 4 web application 
2- from the inner window choose Web Api

Comment: Hi user2388935, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, that is not true. As I mentioned "I know for sure it supposed to be there since I have it at work". You don't necessarily have to choose MVC in order to use it.

Comment: In VS2012 is under that option. Solved my issue at least! I know in VS2015 is already stated as a possible option to be chossen from the create project menu.